# Assingning unique id and names?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a html table with one prototype row. Prototype row has few tds and each td has input element. I am trying to clone the row and assign unique ids and names. But in Fire fox new ids and names are assigned properly. But in IE unique ids and names are not assigned. This logic works fine in FF. But in IE7 it does not work.

### html Table:

```
<table class="myTable">
 <tr class="prototype">
    <td>
       <label for="myValue1">MY Value ONE:</label><br>
    <input class="required email" id="myValue1" type="text" value="" name="myValue1">
    </td>
     <td>
       <label for="myValue2">MY Value TWO:</label><br>
    <input class="required email" id="myValue2" type="text" value="" name="myValue2">
    </td>
     <td>
       <label for="myValue3">MY Value THREE:</label><br>
    <input class="required email" id="myValue3" type="text" value="" name="myValue3">
    </td>
    <td>
       <label for="myValue4">MY Value FOUR:</label><br>
    <input class="required email" id="myValue4" type="text" value="" name="myValue4">
    </td> 
 </tr>

</table>
```

### JQuery code:

```
$("#new").click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
               var d = new Date();
        var counter = d.getTime(); 
        var master = $("table.myTable");
        var prot = master.find("tr.prototype").clone();
        prot.removeClass('prototype');
        prot.addClass("contact");
        prot.find("#myValue1").attr('id',"myValue1"+counter);
        prot.find("#myValue2").attr('id',"myValue2"+counter);
        prot.find("#myValue3").attr('id',"myValue3"+counter);
        prot.find("#myValue4").attr('id',"myValue4"+counter);

        prot.find("#myValue1"+counter).attr('name',"myValue1"+counter);
        prot.find("#myValue2"+counter).attr('name',"myValue2"+counter);
        prot.find("#myValue3"+counter).attr('name',"myValue3"+counter);
        prot.find("#myValue4"+counter).attr('name',"myValue4"+counter);

            jQuery('table.myTable tr:last').before(prot);

    });
```

But with the above code unique ids and names are not assigned.am i doing anything wrong here?

Thanks!

Comment: Perhaps because IE is getting fussy about the fact that since the master already contains ID's and you are trying to clone them.  Try starting off without ID's in the master and only adding them after the clone.  To select your separate `myValue` inputs you can add a class instead of an ID in the master.

Comment: A much simpler solution would be to remove the `id` attributes and not change the names and pass the values across as a comma delimited string which you can turn into an array and loop through on the server side.

Comment: I tried..but no use..

Answer (score 2):

You don't needs IDs:

```
<label>MY Value ONE:<br /><input class="required email" type="text" name="myValue1[]" /></label>
```

Now you can clone this label as many times as needed, and it'll work.

On the server side, you can then access (for example in PHP) `$_POST['myValue1']` as an array.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry to tell you, but everything seems fine with what you did. I tried the example you gave on IE and it seems to work.

If you inspect it with Developer Tools you still see the old id? what version of IE?

here is the code I tried:

```
<html>
<head>

<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script>
<script>


$(function() {
    $("#new").click(function(e) {

        e.preventDefault();
        var d = new Date();
        var counter = d.getTime(); 
        var master = $("table.myTable");
        var prot = master.find("tr.prototype").clone();
        prot.removeClass('prototype');
        prot.addClass("contact");

        //$(prot.find("input")[0])
        prot.find("#myValue1").attr('id',"myValue1"+counter);
        prot.find("#myValue2").attr('id',"myValue2"+counter);
        prot.find("#myValue3").attr('id',"myValue3"+counter);
        prot.find("#myValue4").attr('id',"myValue4"+counter);

        prot.find("#myValue1"+counter).attr('name',"myValue1"+counter);
        prot.find("#myValue2"+counter).attr('name',"myValue2"+counter);
        prot.find("#myValue3"+counter).attr('name',"myValue3"+counter);
        prot.find("#myValue4"+counter).attr('name',"myValue4"+counter);

            jQuery('table.myTable tr:last').before(prot);
        counter++;
    });
});

</script>
</head>
<body>

<table class="myTable">
 <tr class="prototype">
    <td>
       <label for="myValue1">MY Value ONE:</label><br>
    <input class="required email" id="myValue1" type="text" value="" name="myValue1">
    </td>
     <td>
       <label for="myValue2">MY Value TWO:</label><br>
    <input class="required email" id="myValue2" type="text" value="" name="myValue2">
    </td>
     <td>
       <label for="myValue3">MY Value THREE:</label><br>
    <input class="required email" id="myValue3" type="text" value="" name="myValue3">
    </td>
    <td>
       <label for="myValue4">MY Value FOUR:</label><br>
    <input class="required email" id="myValue4" type="text" value="" name="myValue4">
    </td> 
 </tr>

</table>

<input type="button" id="new" />

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. IE7 am using. i inspected using ie developer tool bar and is showing the ids of prototype row.

Comment: I tried it on IE10 - which I'm guessing works more like FF or Chrome than IE7. any reason to still try so hard to be compatible with IE7?