# JQuery validation plugin gives error?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am using JQuery validation plugin.

```
<script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.11.0/jquery.validate.js"></script>
```

Jquery code:

```
function validateForm(){


        $('[name^="attribute"]').each(function(){
        $(this).rules("add", {
            required: true,
            messages: {
                required: "Mandatory field"
            }
        } );            
    });



    $('[name^="valueAttribute"]').each(function(){
        $(this).rules("add", {
            required: true,
            maxlength: 12,
            email: true,
            messages: {
                required: "Enter email",
                email: "Enter valid email",
                maxlength: "Maximum 12 characters"
            }
        } );            
    });


        return $("#myForm").validate({
          onfocusout: function(element) { jQuery(element).valid(); } 
    });

  }
```

But above script gives error as below.

```
TypeError: $.data(...) is undefined
```

am i doing anything wrong here? It works fine if i remove all for each and go with default messages.

Thanks!

Comment: do you have a jsfiddle?

Answer (score 0):

The only problem seems to be, you are adding the rules to the elements before the `validator` plugin is initialized for the form

```
<script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.11.0/jquery.validate.js"></script>
<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-validate/1.11.1/additional-methods.js"></script>
```

then

```
jQuery(function ($) {
    function validateForm(){
        var validator = $("#myForm").validate({
            onfocusout: function(element) { jQuery(element).valid(); } 
        });

        $('[name^="attribute"]').each(function(){
            $(this).rules("add", {
                required: true,
                messages: {
                    required: "Mandatory field"
                }
            } );            
        });

        $('[name^="valueAttribute"]').each(function(){
            $(this).rules("add", {
                required: true,
                maxlength: 12,
                email: true,
                messages: {
                    required: "Enter email",
                    email: "Enter valid email",
                    maxlength: "Maximum 12 characters"
                }
            } );            
        });

        return validator;

    }

});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/Mr9mH/)

Comment: I tried the code. But it is giving different error now.TypeError: $.validator.methods[method] is undefined

Comment: @user1016403 you are missing the `additional-methods.js` script

Comment: even after including additional-methods.js am getting same error..Any clue?

Comment: @user1016403 it is because of an invalid rulename

Comment: @user1016403 what are the other rules used

Comment: @user1016403 can you share the details of the form and the input elements

Comment: My input elements are as below: i create input elements as http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18354355/assingning-unique-id-and-names/18354784?noredirect=1#comment26948512_18354784

Answer (score 0):

you are not using `$(document).ready();`

try this

```
$(document).ready(function(){
     // do script here
});
```

hope it will help